# Как автоматически перенаправлять http на https в веб приложении Java

Tags: java, https

Как автоматически перенаправлять http на https в веб приложении Java

В web.xml добавляю следующий код, где `App` – имя проекта, также пытаюсь в `searching.jsp` сделать перенаправление на https

```
     <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>App</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
  
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Non-SecureResource</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/searching.jsp</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>/somepath/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
```

Настройка Tomcat 7 (Локальный), но в последующем нужно на сервере

```
Tomcat admin port  8005
HTTP/1.1           9097
AJP/1.3            8009
```

Идет на пере направление с `http://localhost:9097/App/`
на

```
https://localhost:8443/App/
```

Результат - `Не удается получить доступ к сайту`

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Ваш томкот точно слушает https на порту 8443 и вообще?

Comment: 8443 нигде не прописывал, он сам загрузился по этому адресу. Может его нужно где-нибудь прописать?

Comment: Вообще-то в руководстве к коту тому есть раздел про https. Вполне возможно, что порт 8443 там уже прописан. Но нужно ему ещё показать, где брать ключи и сертификаты, которые возможно придётся предварительно изготовить. Без этого https никак не заработает. Это всё тоже описано в руководстве. Убедитесь, что конфигурация Вашего сервера соответствует тому, что там написано.

Comment: `Не удается получить доступ к сайту` - потому что security-constraint

Comment: Да, если убрать security-constraint, то все грузится, с обычным http